# how to add the element into hashmap in java not getting add in HashMap

Tags: java, collections

I am new to java i got error in HashMap
this is what i tried

```
Hashmap h=new HashMap();
h.put(1,"java");
h.put(2,"c");
```

but got error

Comment: it should be `HashMap` not `Hashmap` with upper `M`

Comment: 1. The class HashMap is written wrong 2. You are using a [raw type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it) which is discouraged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use DataTypes Also Like
this is the older procedure to store the values in hashmap

```
HashMap<Integer,String> h=new HashMap<Integer,String>();
h.put(1,"java");
h.put(2,"c");
```

It will Work

Answer (score 0):

For better quality code and low coupling you should use MAP.

```
Map<Integer,String> h= new HashMap<>();
            h.put(1,"java");
            h.put(2,"c");
```